# Entity Framework 4.1 and geography type

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I know that the geography sql type isn't supported in the entity framework. It is coming though and is previewed in the June 11 CTP...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

My question is when is this going live or is it already live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be part of .NET 4.5 so once .NET 4.5, VS 11 and probably also Windows 8 will be released spatial types will be available.